# QuickBooks PHP DevKit failure to connect

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have a application set up and have changed my config file to contain the development token and keys from that application.  When I run the oauth script, I get to the page where it says I am not connected, and has the button to connect.  Upon clicking that button, I get a pop up window that is directed to https://appcenter.intuit.com/NotFound, and it says "Sorry, we can't find the page you are looking for".  I am unsure what I am doing wrong at this point.

I would like to connect to my existing Quickbooks Online account so that I can use the Sandbox accounts I have already set up so I can test some new functionality that I am trying to incorporate into my existing application.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check the URLs in your config file
- Check the URLs in your application configuration on Intuit's site
- Check the URLs in your Javascript

If you still can't figure out what's wrong, actually post your code so that someone might be able to actually help you.